# override mongoid document find

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

Considering an existing database of normal Mongoid documents, I'm implementing unique slugs for these documents, and have overwritten the find method as such:

```
def self.find(id)
    Post.any_of({:_id => id}, {:slug => id}).first
end
```

However, when I run `Post.all` or `Post.first` in the console, it always returns nil. Works fine on classes that I have no overwritten the find method.

How can I override this with keeping the functionality of other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overwriting find, I just created a new method find_by_id_or_slug and updated my code appropriately.